# "Undefined" coming as output of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am newbie to Javascript and the syntax just bugs me. The output is giving me undefined as an alert after every function declaration output.

```
let func=[
    {
        sayHi:function(){
            alert('hello');
        },
        saybi:function(){
            alert('Bye');
        }
    },
    {
        sayName:function(name){
            alert('Hii !! ', +name);
        },
        askName:function(){
            alert("What's your name ??");
        }
    }
];

alert(func[0].sayHi());

let name=prompt("What's your name ?","");
if(name!="")
{
    alert(func[1].sayName(name));
}
else{
    alert(func[1].askName());
}
```

Comment: Actually if u notice i just gave a comma between so func[1] is defined. The thing is that the output does come but after that undefined comes consequently

Comment: Formatting code is important for readability, :)

Answer (score 2):

functions in `func` array call `alert` function. But you have called `alert` again after invoking a function like `alert(func[0].sayHi())`.

You should call function like below:

```js
let func = [{
    sayHi: function() {
      alert('hello');
    },
    saybi: function() {
      alert('Bye');
    }
  },
  {
    sayName: function(name) {
      alert('Hii !! ' + name);
    },
    askName: function() {
      alert("What's your name ??");
    }
  }
];

func[0].sayHi();

let name = prompt("What's your name ?", "");
if (name != "") {
  func[1].sayName(name);
} else {
  func[1].askName();
}
```

**Update:** I've fixed `sayName` function to work properly.

Comment: Or just return the strings (either `'hello'` or `'bye'`) from those functions with an `alert` call below. But your answer is clearer I guess. The overall point is that those functions returned **nothing**, hence the `undefined` after calling `alert` with those functions as parameters.

Comment: Thanks !! It helped. Keep helping us newbies. :p

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to wrap every function call with alert() as those functions returns undefined and confuses you. Also alert() takes one argument, so the comma (',') there isn't helping.

Try this:

```js
let func = [
    {
      sayHi: function(){
        alert('hello');
      },
      saybi: function(){
        alert('Bye');
      },
    },{
      sayName: function(name) {
        alert('Hi !! ' + name);
      },
      askName: function() {
        alert("What's your name ??");
      },
    }];

func[0].sayHi();

let name = prompt("What's your name ?", "");
if (name != "") {
    func[1].sayName(name);
} else {
    func[1].askName();
}
```

Comment: Great !! Thanks for Help.

Answer (score 0):

It works perfect. sayHi() returns nothing so it returns undefined. That is it what you are alerting in the last line.